# Does ActiveMQ store non-persistent message for inactive durable message subscriber in kahadb?

Tags: activemq-classic, kahadb

I was reading http://activemq.apache.org/amq-message-store.html and was not able to determine whether ActiveMQ store non-persistent message for inactive durable message subscriber in kahadb or in memory (and offload to disk for tempUsage)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-persistent messages sent to a Topic are never stored in KahaDB as they are non-persistent, only persistent message are written into the KahaDB store as that is how the delivery guarantees are met.

Comment: same is with queue right? Also, I am not able to find mbean detail for StoreMessageSize for a destination. I believe that this should provide some information on size of kahadb used by this destination for storing message. BUt what is the unit, is it Byte, KB?